# pandasの表の処理方法に悩んでいます

Tags: python, pandas

pythonのpandasを使ったデータ加工方法で悩んでおります。
どなたかご教授お願いいたします。
以下のようなデータを加工したいです。

このデータを

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([[1,'ame', 30,'hare',40],[2,'kumori', 20,'kosame',30]], columns=['id','today_tenki', 'today_ondo', 'tommow_tenki', 'tommorow_ondo'])
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようなデータに変換したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
pandasのmeltやstackを使ってこのような処理ができると思ったのですが、うまくいかず。

Answer (score 1):

以下は [numpy.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) を使う場合です。

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'ame', 30,'hare',40],
    [2,'kumori', 20,'kosame',30]
  ], columns=['id', 'today_tenki', 'today_ondo', 'tommorow_tenki', 'tommorow_ondo'])

>>> df
   id today_tenki  today_ondo tommorow_tenki  tommorow_ondo
0   1         ame          30         hare             40
1   2      kumori          20       kosame             30

>>> dfn = pd.DataFrame(
  np.concatenate((
    df[['id', 'today_tenki', 'today_ondo']].values,
    df[['id', 'tommorow_tenki', 'tommorow_ondo']].values
  )), columns=('id', 'tenki', 'ondo')
).sort_values('id', ignore_index=True)

>>> dfn
  id   tenki ondo
0  1     ame   30
1  1    hare   40
2  2  kumori   20
3  2  kosame   30
```

Answer (score 0):

2つのデータフレームに分割して、カラム名を変更、結合とソートで処理しました。
もっとスマートが方法があるかもしれません。

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'ame', 30,'hare',40],[2,'kumori', 20,'kosame',30]], columns=['id','today_tenki', 'today_ondo', 'tommow_tenki', 'tommorow_ondo'])
df1 = df[['id', 'today_tenki','today_ondo']]
df2 = df[['id', 'tommow_tenki','tommorow_ondo']]
df2.columns = df1.columns
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='id')
new_df.columns = ['id', 'tenki', 'ondo']
```